# Textbf not working for subscript

Tags: bold, subscripts, syntax

```
\textbf{C$_{global\_binary}$}
```

The above is the code I use, the generate text is
[image]

I want to make "global_binary" subscript also in bold, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the material doesn't appear to be math-y, I would recommend using `\textsubscript` rather than TeX's math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textbf{C\textsubscript{global\_binary}}

C\textsubscript{global\_binary}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `\textbf`, as the name implies, applies to text (as opposed to math. Using `\mathbf` (inside math mode) gives you

```
$\mathbf{C_{global\_binary}}$
```

as your input and

[image: boldface C with global_binary as subscript]

as your output